# How to get, delete and update nic dhcp of azure through poweshell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Define user:

```
$userName = " xxxx"
```

Set password:

```
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
```

Set credentials:

```
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $Pwd
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $creds
Get-AzSubscription
Set-AzContext -Subscription  "xxxxxxxxxx"
Get-AzVM 
Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName rba-test-rg
```

Comment: Please add some context to explain the code sections.

Comment: Hi, I have to write some powershell script to get the network interface of azure under a particular vm, and delete the network interface , and update the network interface dhcp therough powershell.

Comment: You should mention this explanation in the question so that people can understand the problem and answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to list the the network interfaces under a particular VM and remove or update it. You can replace `{nic needs to be deleted}` and `{nic needs to be updated}` with your own conditional statement:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName {resource group name} -Name {VM name}  
$nics = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
foreach($nic in $nics){
    $aznics = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $nic.id
    if({nic needs to be deleted}){
        $aznics | Remove-AzNetworkInterface
    }
    if({nic needs to be updated}){
        $aznics.DnsSettings.DnsServers.Add("192.168.1.100");
        $aznics | Set-AzNetworkInterface
    }
}
```